# PHP explode, save the "leftovers"

Tags: php, explode

In this scenario everything works as expected:

```
$someString = '1|2|3|4';
list($val1, $val2, $val3, $val4) = explode("|", $someString);
```

In the followin scenario there are more values in the $someString than what there are $vals to put them in:

```
$someString = '1|2|3|4|5|6';
list($val1, $val2, $val3, $val4) = explode("|", $someString);
```

How can I make it so that in the 2nd case the $val4 would be 4|5|6 instead of just 4, or how do I put these "leftovers" at the end of the $val4 without adding $val5, $val6 etc. so it would be 456?

Comment: `explode("|", $someString, 4)` [It's right there in the docs, man](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [PHP `explode` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) can accept a third optional parameter called `$limit`:

> If `limit` is set and positive, the returned array will contain a maximum of `limit` elements with the last element containing the rest of `string`.
>
> If the `limit` parameter is negative, all components except the last `-limit` are returned.
>
> If the `limit` parameter is zero, then this is treated as `1`.

So by that logic, you should use `explode("|", $someString, 4)`:

```
$someString = '1|2|3|4|5|6';
list($val1, $val2, $val3, $val4) = explode("|", $someString, 4);
echo $val1; // 1
echo $val2; // 2
echo $val3; // 3
echo $val4; // 4|5|6
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought the limit would leave all the rest unnoted, but seems that is not the case. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case you can use the limiting clause of the `explode` function.  In general though, there's not a clean way of catching the "leftovers" of a `list()` assignment although we can make it work.

[The documentation of `list()`](http://php.net/list) says that the return value is the assigned array.

For example:

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
var_dump(list($a, $b, $c) = $arr);
/*
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "d"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "e"
}
*/

var_dump($a, $b, $c);
/*
string(1) "a"
string(1) "b"
string(1) "c"
*/
```

We can exploit this with `array_slice()` to extract the leftovers *and* do the assignment at the same time:

```
$leftovers = array_slice( list($a, $b, $c) = $arr, 3);
```

This has the same effect as doing:

```
$temp = operation_to_build_array();

list($a, $b, $c) = $temp;
$leftovers = array_slice($temp, 3);
```